# Work Flow Security Permissions

Tags: security, multisite, workflow

I have a template and apply `Publishing workflow` on this template, I created items from this template in 2 different sites, I created 2 different users for each site,I want when the item in "site 1" move to another state to show in `Work Box` when i logged in by "user 1" and not show in the `Work Box` when i logged in by "user 2".

So each user only approve item in his site and do not see item in another site.

Is there way to apply this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the item from the same template and using the same workflow. So simplest way is to apply the security at site level to achieve your requirement.

For ex, create two new roles role1 and role2. Restrict read access for the role role1 at site level, so any user who are part of role1 will not have access to any of the item in site1. Do the similar steps for role2 and site2. Assign these roles to user1 and user2 respectively.